# Wordpress site shows "Index of/"

Tags: wordpress, hostmonster

Reinstalled WP on my server and it now shows this: http://www.mtthwbsh.com

I've done some reading and have only found information on changing the HTaccess but am not really sure what this entails. If anyone has had this problem and could offer some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got your resume and other files exposed on that directory.  I would recommend removing them unless you want the whole world to have them....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an `.htaccess` issue.  All you need is to install the `index.php` file into the directory.  Without it, there's nothing for the site to load by default.

Comment: So I would need to move the index.php of my custom theme out of the themes folder and into my root folder?

Comment: No.  You need the index file from WordPress.  When you download WordPress, in the root directory (right next to wp-config.php) is an index.php file.  You need that installed there.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I'm so sorry for wasting your time. I totally forgot to include the one from the WP install to enable themes. Thanks for your help.